# How to find the min value between two different datetime using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

`(Not duplicate / my question is entirely different)`

My `dataframe` looks like this:

```
# [df2] is day based

time             time2
2017-01-01,      2017-01-01 00:12:00
2017-01-02,      2017-01-02 03:15:00
2017-01-03,      2017-01-03 01:25:00
2017-01-04,      2017-01-04 04:12:00
2017-01-05,      2017-01-05 00:45:00
....

# [df] is minute based

time                     value
2017-01-01 00:01:00,     0.1232
2017-01-01 00:02:00,     0.1232
2017-01-01 00:03:00,     0.1232
2017-01-01 00:04:00,     0.1232
2017-01-01 00:05:00,     0.1232
....
```

I want to create a new column called `time_val_min` in `[df2]` that finds the `min` value between `df2['time2']` and `df2['time']` form `[df]` within the range specified in `df2['time']`  and `df2['time2']`

**What did I do?**

I did `df2['time_val_min'] = df[df['time'].dt.hour.between(df2['time'], df2['time'])].min()` but it does not work.

Could you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: How long are `df` and `df2`?

Comment: `df` is a minute based dataset from `2017` to `2018` and similarly `df2` is a daily dataset from `2107` to `2018`. However, we do not need to iterate all of `df` since it depends on the range of `df2`

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two data frame on date, and filter the time:

```
# create the date from the time column
df['date'] = df['time'].dt.normalize()

# merge
new_df = (df.merge(df2, left_on='date',    # left on date
                   right_on='time',        # right on time, if time is purely beginning of days
                   how='right',
                   suffixes=['','_y'])
            .query('time < time2')
            .groupby('date')
            ['time'].min()
            .to_frame(name='time_val_min')
            .merge(df2, right_on='time', left_index=True)
           )
```

Output:

```
         time_val_min       time               time2
0 2017-01-01 00:01:00 2017-01-01 2017-01-01 00:12:00
```

Comment: I need the `time_val_min` column which is the minimum value between the `time` and `time2`.

Comment: I need the `min` value aswell :)